# Is there a way to use a method as an input variable for another method in Java?

Tags: java

I attempted to create a method which calculates the sum of the values of another method in the same way the capital sigma notation does in math. I wanted it to use successive natural numbers as input variables for the function and use recursion to sum it all up. However, as I wanted to create a method for general summation, I am not sure how to assign another (single variable) method as an input variable.

I thought of something like this:

```
    public static int sum(int lowerbound, int upperbound, function(int x)){
        int partialsum = 0;
        for (int i = lowerbound; i <= upperbound; i++){
        partialsum = partialsum + function(i);
        }
        return partialsum;
    }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; but you would need to pass a [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) (Java is not JavaScript). Like,

```
public static int sum(int lowerbound, int upperbound, IntFunction<Integer> function) {
    int partialsum = 0;
    for (int i = lowerbound; i <= upperbound; i++) {
        partialsum = partialsum + function.apply(i);
    }
    return partialsum;
}
```

And then to use it, something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sum(1, 10, a -> a));
}
```

Which outputs

```
55
```

It isn't clear what result you would expect (or what function you intended to pass).

Comment: I am new to programming and want to incorporate it into solving my math homework. Right now it's just practice for me. Originally I tried to write a program which approximates the [Kempner Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series) and I then I wanted to sum up some probabilities from Bernoulli trials.

Comment: [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html) Is probably a better choice

Answer (score 0):

You pass in a [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html)

```
public static int sum(int lowerbound, int upperbound, IntUnaryOperator func) { 
    ...
    partialsum += func.applyAsInt(i);
```

Then, either pass a method in, or use a lambda:

```
sum(1, 2, n -> n * 2)
```